# jQuery DateRangePicker - When changing start date, the end date also changes - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I change the start date, the end date on my calendar changes to be the same. I want the start date to have no effect on the end date.

[image: jquery calendar]

```
<input id="date" name="range">


$(function() { $("#date").daterangepicker(); });
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. You need two fields if you want a range

Comment: It's just setting a default value for the second date as it can't be any earlier than the start date.

Comment: may be you should try the predefined custom arge http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve as it's not clear from your explanation..

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your calendar as in the jQuery docs, you wont have this issue - you need two separate inputs for the date range:

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Currently it appears to be changing the end date so it is no earlier than the start date range.